# How do I use Unlockables in Marvel Heroic Roleplaying to represent a mentor?

Tags: marvel-heroic-roleplaying

I'm busy preparing a Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles game using the Marvel Heroic Roleplaying (MHR) system. It was suggested to me that I use Master Splinter as an Unlockable, but I'm not really sure how that would work. Slightly related, I'm also thinking of making April and Casey Unlockables in the same way.

I haven't played a game of MHR yet, so it will be my first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many different ways to cast an NPC as an Unlockable resource. Here are a few:

1. **Resource for the duration of an Act**: This is a pretty simple way to model this kind of support. Usually for 5 XP, the hero has a d8
   or d10 Resource for the entire Act to represent Master Splinter's
   help.

   Alternatives to this method include, instead of a Resource (which precludes the use of other resources unless you spend additional PP), cast the NPC as

   - a temporary additional Power Set (see Lockheed the Dragon on the Shadowcat character sheet [BR86])
   - a temporary SFX (see "SFX: Redwing" on the Falcon character sheet [CW178])

   You may want to price these at 10 or even 15 XP, depending on how powerful you make them.
2. **Unlock as a playable character**: If you're playing a troupe style game, where the players play a collection of different heroes throughout the story, you allow them to spend 5, 10, or 15 XP (depending on how desirable the character is) to have that character as one of their playable options.
3. **NPC shows up to help in scene of their choice**: In this case, the character shows up as an actual Watcher character for one scene of the player's choice and supports them in the scene. Again, you'll probably want to cost this according to the popularity or effectiveness of the NPC (5, 10, or 15 XP). As a Watcher char., on their turn they'll either be lending a die from their sheet to the player, or using an applicable trait die from their sheet as an effect die to inflict something on the player's opponents. (Alternately you can allow the player to play both themselves and the NPC if you're comfortable with players controlling multiple characters in a scene.)